# Component view not getting updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a common pagination component. It has logic implemented in it as well as UI.

When I implement it in a parent component, wrapping it with condition causes a problem as the view is not getting updated. But when I unwrap it from condition, it gets updated view as it should.

The `pager` array which is a state in `Pagination` contains page numbers.

I have added problem in the screenshot below. The first one displays correctly as pager array contains `4,5,6,...` but latter one's view is still not updated but its current page is selected as same as the first one[image: Pagination screenshot]

The screenshot where it is implemented in parent component for is:
[image]

Comment: This seems like an issue in the Pagination component. Is it one you made yourself or are you using a framework? If you made it yourself, could you post the source code for it? It would make it a lot easier to help you find the problem.

Comment: I made it myself. Yes I have updated source code

Comment: Why are you returning a string instead of an html element?

Comment: Just as something to print as fallback, should I place some component?

Comment: pager is an inner state of pagination component. isLoading property of your parent component state resets the pager everytime isLoading changes - that may cause some issues :)

ps. returning string/component/null makes no difference here - just demounting/mounting Pagination everytime

Comment: Yes @Kejt ! You are correct, that is in fact reseting `Pagination` component everytime.

Comment: hope I helped you solve your issue :)

Comment: Yes, it helped me to track down the issue